# Sh Script Help - Grading Papers

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

How do I make the average grade show a decimal point?

Instead of showing Average Grade = 33%. I want it to show Average Grade = 33.3333%

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

read -p "Number of Papers To Grade: " numpap

av=$numpap

while [ $av -gt 0 ];

do
  av=$(($av - 1))
 echo "Enter a Number (1-100): "
read num
if [[ $num -ge 1 && $num -le 100 ]] ; then
     echo ""
   else
     print "NOT in 1-100 range"
     av=$(($av + 1))
     total=$(($total - num))
   fi
total=$(($total + num))
done

averag=$(($total/$numpap))

echo "Average Grade = $averag%"

echo "Done"

Comment: It is bad design to ask up-front how many papers to grade.  Just read inputs until there are no more.  Then report the average.

Comment: Super easy just create a loop to ask for a grade or finished imputing then calculate average and quit

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints that might point you in the right direction.

Check the `bash` man page on `while` loops, the `read` builtin, and evaluating math expressions with the `$((...))` construct.

For another approach, you might also look into `for` loops, the `$(...)` construct and the man page for the `seq` command.

That should give you some pieces to the puzzle. Good luck!